# Xcode: finding a variable value while setting a breakpoint

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am a seasoned Visual Studio programmer, and when I set a breakpoint, I can open an intermediate window and type `?variableName` to view the current value of the variable.

In Xcode however, I can't seem to find an equivalent. I can hover over the variable name when stepping through the code, but long strings are truncated in the view.

Is there an Xcode equivalent to the intermediate window of Visual Studio?  If not, how can I set a breakpoint and watch the value (the full value in the case of longer strings)?

Many thanks,
Brett

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the console window (under the Run menu - choose "Show console") and then it's a gdb debugger. Then you can issue:

```
po variableName
```

Another way is to hover over the variable, right-click (or [Ctrl]+[left-click]) and choose "Print Description". The output will be sent to the gdb console.

Comment: I don't find the "Print Description" item. And is the print self breakpoint function working with primitives like int?

Comment: **"po"** is for objects (Print Object), while **"print"** is for primitives.

Comment: Sometimes you'll have to cast primitives, especially if you're doing some kind of transformation, e.g. **`po (int)[myNSNumber intValue]`**

Answer (score 0):

There is a debugger GUI you can open by clicking the little spray bottle next to the step commands (or through Run > Debugger). It has a GUI window with pretty much all the objects in the frame you're looking at and the current call stack.